# unable to show the collection in mongodb for the selected db

Tags: mongodb, collections

I am able to run the command show collections but it is not listing any results including system.indexes. I have also dumped the sample data in to the DB but still it doesn't work.

Please help me with suggestions.

Comment: Did you switch to a database before you ran `show collections` command?

Comment: no i havent done that

Comment: You should use the command `show dbs` and then switch to one of the listed dbs for e.g. `use admin`. Issuing the `show collections` command now should give you the list of all collections in the db including `system.indexes`.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, I am selecting the database by using `use db` command but still when i run `show collections` it only give the list of document collections but not the `system.indexes`